# CS231n: Total memory of VGGnet

Tags: memory, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm reading this CS231n tutorial, about convolutional neural networks. They give an example about VGGNet:

http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

> VGGNet in detail. Lets break down the VGGNet in more detail as a case
>   study. The whole VGGNet is composed of CONV layers that perform 3x3
>   convolutions with stride 1 and pad 1, and of POOL layers that perform
>   2x2 max pooling with stride 2 (and no padding). We can write out the
>   size of the representation at each step of the processing and keep
>   track of both the representation size and the total number of weights:

Then they give a detailed calculation of the network structure:
[image]

But the thing is, for total memory, the tutorial gives the result of 24M, but when I calculated it I only got about 15M ! I simply added all of the memories:

```
>>> 224*224*(3+64*2)+112*112*(64+128*2)+56*56*(128+256*3)+28*28*(256+512*3)+14*14*(512*4)+7*7*512+4096+4096+1000
15237608
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice catch! Your calculation is correct, total memory of VGG representation is indeed

```
15.2M * 4 bytes ~= 61Mb
```

In fact, this error has been [reported](https://github.com/cs231n/cs231n.github.io/issues/88) long time ago, but unfortunately CS231n staff doesn't spend too much time on website maintenance...

However, note that if you code VGG network in any framework (Caffe, Tensorflow, etc), the total model size will include the parameters and this part is much larger, as the authors also show in their calculations (which seems right).

Comment: I have a follow up question: Suppose the framework is using im2col (I'm asking this because at first I thought the missing 9M is due to im2col....) then we have to add the amount of memory made by stacking the layers into overlapping columns right? For example from POOL2- [28x28x256] to CONV3-512: [28x28x512], following the "Implementation as Matrix multiplication" part we would have the size of the stacked columns to be (3*3*128) x (28*28). We would then do this for every conv layer, then find the maximum, that would then be the amount to add. Am I correct?

Comment: @DangManhTruong I think you should ask it as a new question, so that I or anybody else can come with a detailed answer

Comment: Ok, here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434465/cs231n-total-memory-of-vggnet-when-using-im2col . Thank you very much